# Why is the program to make Windows 7 automatic log on called "netplwiz"? Is it available in the Control Panel?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, passwords, automatic-logon

So it is stated on websites such as howtogeek.com that to automatically log on to Windows 7, type netplwiz in the box after we click the Windows Start icon, or press WinKey + R and type in netplwiz.

A question is, what does "netplwiz" stand for?  "Net Please Wiz?"  It is a strange way to configure something.

Is this available by using the Control Panel instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't know what netplwiz stands for.
I do know it's *not* available in the control panel by default.
There are ways to add it though. You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/138368-user-accounts-netplwiz-control-panel.html):
Scroll to the bottom and download and execute the right .reg file (there's one to add the applet and one to remove it again).

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record.

Netplwiz stands for "Network places wizard".